# How to efficiently write a large sequence of NULL bytes in a file?

Tags: c, performance, system-calls

I have an file descriptor *fd*, an offset and a length, and I need to write *length* `NULL` bytes from *offset* in the file described by *fd* (note: it never occurs at the end of the file).

Is there an efficient way to do that aside from using a buffer filled with `NULL`s and repeatedly writing it in a loop? The sequence of `NULL`s may goes up to 16Mo and I currently use a buffer of size 512 (= ~30k calls to `write(2)`).

Comment: did you tried somme thing?

Comment: your buffer size should be a multiple of the block size of the underlying file system. e.g. if you're using 4k blocks, then you should be using a 4k, 8k, 12k, etc... buffer size.

Comment: @MOHAMED, clearly the OP has, he uses a 512 byte buffer and writes n times...

Comment: The overhead of the loop is so small compared to disk I/O that it wouldn't even register as overhead if you benchmarked it. You're trying to optimize something that doesn't need optimizing.

Comment: @Marc B: Why? the kernel is not going to push the data into disk until a block is ready unless you call `fsync`.

Comment: @NikosC.: It does need optimizing. At one syscall per 512 bytes, somewhere around 10-50% of the time will be spent entering and exiting kernelspace, not actually doing any useful work. Something in the range 4k-64k is more reasonable.

Comment: What do you mean by efficient ? Running time ? In that case, some `write`s of size about the same as block/buffer cache size. In line of codes ? In that case `mmap` and `bzero`, performance is interesting here because you let the system choose the right way to write the data.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès In this case, I care more about memory than time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `mmap`ing the file at the desired offset and mapping in exactly the required size, and then simply calling `memset`.

EDIT: Based on the code posted by @jthill, here is a simple example which demonstrates how to do a comparison..

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void create(int fsize)
{
  FILE *fd = fopen("data", "wb");
  fseek(fd, fsize - 1, SEEK_SET);
  fputc(0, fd);
  fclose(fd);
}

void seek_write(const char* data, int wsize, int seek, int dsize)
{
  int fd = open("data", O_RDWR);
  // Now seek_write
  if (lseek(fd, seek, SEEK_SET) != seek)
    perror("seek?"), abort();
  // Now write in requested blocks..
  for (int c = dsize / wsize; c--;)
    if (write(fd, data, wsize) != wsize)
      perror("write?"), abort();
  close(fd);
}

void mmap_memset(int wsize, int seek, int dsize)
{
  int fd = open("data", O_RDWR);
  void* map = mmap(0, dsize + seek, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (map == MAP_FAILED)
    perror("mmap?"), abort();
  memset((char*)map + seek, 0, dsize);
  munmap(map, dsize);
  close(fd);
}

int main(int c, char **v)
{
  struct timeval start, end;
  long long ts1, ts2;
  int wsize = c>1 ? atoi(*++v) : 512;
  int seek  = c>2 ? atoi(*++v) : 0;
  int reps  = c>3 ? atoi(*++v) : 1000;
  int dsize = c>4 ? atoi(*++v) : 16*1024*1024;
  int fsize = c>5 ? atoi(*++v) : 32*1024*1024;

  // Create the file and grow...
  create(fsize);

  char *data = mmap(0, wsize, PROT_READ, MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, 0, 0);

  printf("Starting write...\n");
  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
  for (int i = 0;i < reps; ++i)
    seek_write(data, wsize, seek, dsize);
  gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

  ts1 = ((end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000) + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);

  printf("Starting mmap...\n");
  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
  for (int i = 0;i < reps; ++i)
    mmap_memset(wsize, seek, dsize);
  gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

  ts2 = ((end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000) + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);

  printf("write: %lld us, %f us\nmmap: %lld us, %f us", ts1, (double)ts1/reps, ts2, (double)ts2/reps);
}
```

NOTES: `mmap` doesn't like it if the offset provided is not aligned (typically on a page boundary), so, its possibly nicer if you can map in the length + offset and simply set from the offset (or alternatively, if you can guarantee a nicely aligned offset, this will work too..)

As you can see, the differences between the two operations are the `lseek` (`map + seek`) and then the `write` (`memset`). I think this is a fair comparison (if anyone wants to fix anything, feel free to.)

I also use `MAP_SHARED` rather than `MAP_PRIVATE`, there is a significant difference between the two, the latter does copy-on-write, which can be much slower!

On my not so powerful system, I get:

```
> ./fwrite 4096 1234
> Starting write...
> Starting mmap...
> write: 14767898 us, 14767.898000 us
> mmap: 6619623 us, 6619.623000 us
```

I think that shows that `mmap` + `memset` is quicker?

Comment: This is unlikely to be any faster than standard methods of writing without `mmap`.

Comment: Seems to me it's going to  be much slower, the kernel doesn't have to read in any blocks it knows are going to be wiped, and it doesn't know that with mmap files.

Comment: @jthill, @R, please check the update, let me know if the little micro-benchmark has anything to fix..

Comment: @jthill it doesn't read from disk until there is a read on a mapped page, if all bytes are written it can push page directly to disk.    No idea why it's 2x faster though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Linux and the filesystem supports sparse files, you could try to punch a hole in your file using `fallocate(2)` with the `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` flag. I would expect that to be fast, although I didn't test it.

Comment: When available, this is the fastest way, but if you plan to subsequently write data over the holes, it may cause bad fragmentation and eventually lead to very bad IO performance.

Comment: @R.. True. If the file currently happens to span continuous blocks, and if he wants to write on the zeroed part later, it might be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can use `splice(2)` to copy data from `/dev/zero`.

That is pretty efficient as most work is done inside the kernel.

Other operating systems may offer a similar facility (i.e `sendfile`).

**update**!

I was forgetting about `fallocate(2)` that can punch holes on the middle of a file.

Comment: I would hesitate to use `splice` or `sendfile` even if they work, because it's very poorly documented what requirements they place on the file descriptors used (must at least one fd to `splice` be a pipe? must `sendfile` write to a socket? etc.) and may even vary between kernel versions.

Comment: You are right `splice(2)` needs one of the file descriptors to be a pipe. I though that limitation has been removed because I was unable to find it on the manual page but it is just there buried on the `ERRORS` section.

Answer (score 1):

From the below, 16M of I/O done badly, just once, is >20ms.  That's verging on perceptible all by itself.

Takeaways:

- I/O deserves attention, because
- doing a lot of it badly makes for deplorable delays.
- 512-byte writes hurt, a lot.
- 4096-byte writes don't.

Offsets either in memory or on disk don't matter so much so `calloc`'ing whatever should do fine (you could try it).

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    int wsiz = c>1 ? atoi(*++v) : 512;
    int seek = c>2 ? atoi(*++v) : 0;
    int woff = c>3 ? atoi(*++v) : 0;
    int fsiz = c>4 ? atoi(*++v) : 16 * 1024 * 1024;
    int reps = c>5 ? atoi(*++v) : 1000;

    printf("writesize %d, seek  %d, align %d, filesize %d, reps %d\n",
           wsiz, seek, woff, fsiz, reps);

    if (wsiz<=0|seek<0|woff<0|fsiz<wsiz)
        return 1;

    int fd = open("data", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0700);
    char *data = mmap(0, 2*wsiz, PROT_READ, MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, 0, 0);

    for (int t = reps; t--; lseek(fd, seek, 0))
        for (int c = fsiz / wsiz; c--;)
            if (write(fd, data+woff, wsiz) != wsiz)
                perror("write?"), abort();

    return close(fd);
}
```

```
cc  -o bin/wipetest -g -O   --std=c11 -march=native -pipe -Wall -Wno-parentheses    wipetest.c
```

```
------------------------------------------------------
writesize 512, seek  0, align 0, filesize 16777216, reps 1000

real    0m20.727s
user    0m0.513s
sys 0m20.220s
------------------------------------------------------
writesize 4096, seek  0, align 0, filesize 16777216, reps 1000

real    0m3.889s
user    0m0.077s
sys 0m3.687s
------------------------------------------------------
writesize 16777216, seek  0, align 0, filesize 16777216, reps 1000

real    0m3.205s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m3.203s
------------------------------------------------------
writesize 512, seek  500, align 0, filesize 16777216, reps 1000

real    0m23.829s
user    0m0.463s
sys 0m23.247s
------------------------------------------------------
writesize 4096, seek  500, align 0, filesize 16777216, reps 1000

real    0m5.531s
user    0m0.053s
sys 0m5.480s
------------------------------------------------------
writesize 16777216, seek  500, align 0, filesize 16777216, reps 1000

real    0m3.435s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m3.433s
------------------------------------------------------
writesize 512, seek  0, align 12, filesize 16777216, reps 1000

real    0m21.478s
user    0m0.537s
sys 0m20.820s
------------------------------------------------------
writesize 4096, seek  0, align 12, filesize 16777216, reps 1000

real    0m3.722s
user    0m0.057s
sys 0m3.667s
------------------------------------------------------
writesize 16777216, seek  0, align 12, filesize 16777216, reps 1000

real    0m3.232s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m3.233s
------------------------------------------------------
writesize 512, seek  500, align 12, filesize 16777216, reps 1000

real    0m23.775s
user    0m0.550s
sys 0m23.113s
------------------------------------------------------
writesize 4096, seek  500, align 12, filesize 16777216, reps 1000

real    0m5.566s
user    0m0.050s
sys 0m5.517s
------------------------------------------------------
writesize 16777216, seek  500, align 12, filesize 16777216, reps 1000

real    0m3.277s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m3.277s
```

Answer (score 0):

`lseek()` to the position and `write()` a large buffer once (or a smaller buffer multiple times).